# Which information does a version 4 UUID carry?

Tags: uuid, privacy

Besides it's random data, I am wondering which information a v4 UUID contains. In [section 4.4](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc4122#section-4.4) of the RFC it says:

> 4.4.  Algorithms for Creating a UUID from Truly Random or
> Pseudo-Random Numbers
>
> The version 4 UUID is meant for generating UUIDs from truly-random or
> pseudo-random numbers.
>
> The algorithm is as follows:
>
> o  Set the two most significant bits (bits 6 and 7) of the
> **clock_seq_hi_and_reserved** to zero and one, respectively.
>
> o  Set the four most significant bits (bits 12 through 15) of the
> **time_hi_and_version** field to the 4-bit version number from
> Section 4.1.3.
>
> o  Set all the other bits to randomly (or pseudo-randomly) chosen
> values.

Seems like clock/time is used for generation? So, from a v4 UUID, can one extract when it was created? If yes, in which detail? Just the seconds of the time or maybe even the date?

Comment: 4 bits wouldn't be enough to identify the date.

Comment: There are no date/time information in UUID v4, the bits are almost all random. Why do you believe it contains date/time information?

Comment: @ScottHunter Not the full date I guess, but at least some part of the date or time it was generated?

Comment: @Progman Because the quote in my questions sounds like some kind of time is used during its generation

Comment: @stefan.at.kotlin No, these are just the names of the fields in the byte layout, see https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc4122#section-4.1.2